# "Speed Mismatch" between 1000T and 10000T?

Tags: ethernet, performance, 10gbethernet, ethtool

I have a server in a data center, which has an Ethernet NIC card with Fibre support. I have a 1Gbps connection and my ISP asked me to make sure the settings on my device are as follows:

```
Full Duplex, 1000meg and NO Auto Negotiation
```

However, I just realized that my NIC only supports 10000T. Here is the output from `ethtool eth2`

```
Settings for eth2:
    Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
    Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full 
    Supports auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Port: FIBRE
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: external
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Supports Wake-on: d
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000014 (20)
                   link ifdown
    Link detected: no
```

I haven't yet connected the cable to the NIC. Do you think there will be a "speed mismatch", as the ISP end is configured at 1000T and my NIC supports only 10000T?

PS: the make/model of NIC is: Mellanox ConnectX-3 En.

Comment: What's the EXACT make and model of NIC?

Comment: Mellanox ConnectX-3 En.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - this card appears to only support 10G.  It is possible that if the card also has an SFP+ slot that it might support 1000baseSX fiber (or similar) but without knowing more about the model of NIC, etc it is hard to say.

Comment: Yes, the card comes with an SFP+ slot. I have the following transreceiver installed: Mellanox MFM1T02A-SR Module

Comment: Yep, 100% 10Gbps only sorry, get another 1Gbs NIC.

Comment: Looking at the specs for the card it appears to be 10G only, so you are likely out of luck unless you use a different NIC.

Answer (score 1):

That's a 10Gbps & 40Gbps **ONLY** NIC - it can't run at any other speed.